# Arduino clean LCD Shield with color codes?

Tags: c, arduino

I thought it would be nice if I could set the background
of the LCD Shield with an color code. I found out, that I just need to say lcd.clean(0xANYCOLOR)

But is there another way? Maybe a better way? :P

Code atm:

```
#include <SparkFunColorLCDShield.h>

LCDShield lcd;

void setup() {
  lcd.init(EPSON);
  lcd.contrast(40);
  lcd.clear(0x0000FF);
}

void loop() {

}
```

Comment: What do you mean with a "cooler" way? What is wrong with what you have? Can you please elaborate?

Comment: _Maybe a "cooler" way_ You can try with a spray color an call Bansky to make a "cool" background.. ;)

Comment: @LPs ... :D I don't think it's a good idea lol

Comment: what's wrong with `lcd.clear(0x0000FF);`?

Comment: It's not wrong but I think there must be another way. I don't like to work only with clear

Comment: if you want to have the whole background of the same colour, that's the most efficient way. For all other purposes, you have `setRect(...), setCircle(...), setPixel(...), printBMP(...), ....` ... it really depends on what are you trying to achieve, and what you expect your *background* to be.

Comment: It is just to learn. Ok thanks for your answer :)

Comment: then i think `printBMP()` is likely to give you the greatest satisfaction ;)

Comment: Ok I will try it :) Just one question left: Why the clear methods in the switch case doesn't work? It works well without switch  case https://hastebin.com/eqojecekov.cpp

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't work? Please **be specific** when you state that there is a problem, and describe **exactly** what you observe. By the way, you should initialize the *random seed* as described [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Random), otherwise your call to `random()` won't be random at all.

Comment: "overflow in implicit constant conversion" on all lcd.clear's
Already saw that Website, but it didn't helped me

Comment: I compiled your code just fine with some random library I found online, could you please provide the link of the *exact* library you are using? The *tip* about *random seed* is to prevent *Arduino* from selecting always the same *background colour* each time you start it.

Comment: https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_Color_LCD_Shield_Arduino_Library/tree/V_1.0

Comment: That's strange, it compiles fine with that library too. I'm using the version `2:1.0.5+dfsg2.4` of the *IDE*

Comment: I am using the latest version for Mac...1.8.1
Yea that's really strange. I am gonna ask my "teacher" : at the moment I am in an internship

Comment: I found out, I had *warnings* disabled. The warning appears on lines `20, 23, 26, 32, 38` only, whereas lines `14, 17, 29` are exempted from it. The reason is that `0xNNNNNN` occupies `24` bits, but the function is defined with `void clear(int color)`, and an `int` on *Arduino* has only `16` bits. Therefore, your value is *narrowed* down with an *overflow* in the conversion. Importantly, a **color** on your *lcd* is defined by `12` bits only, *e.g.: `BLACK = 0x000, MAGENTA = 0xF0F, INDIGO = 0x408, ...`*, so you should definitively change your constants.

Comment: If you want to go *fully random*, you could try this: `randomSeed(analogRead(0)); int bgcolor = random(); lcd.clear(bgcolor & 0x0FFF);`

Comment: You are great. I love you <3 
Works fine

Comment: Sorry that I annoy you, but is there a way to clear with a html color code? Like #FFFFFF

Comment: Since the two *color spaces* have different precision you cannot use `0xABCDEF` directly, but you can **[map](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map)** colours from one *color space* to the *other*, *e.g. `bgcolor = map(html_color, 0, 0xFFFFFF, 0, 0xFFF);`*. Or is your question how to [convert a string](https://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?topic=105227.0) '#FFFFFF' to an int value?

Comment: I found a way :) I am converting the hex to a decimal :)

Comment: At the moment this is my code: https://hastebin.com/zilaramune.cpp
But it's not working 100%. I think number is null, but at the moment I don't know why

Comment: `Serial.read()` reads only *one byte*, not a *String*, see **[documentation](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Read)**. Also, if you send values like this `#ABCDEF` then you need to get rid of the leading `#` symbol before converting the value. Beware of possible trailing `\r\n` in your input. About **strtol**, note that you should use **map** anyway because your **html** hex values have a different *bits width*.

Comment: Hm. I am not using any #...I am just using "FFFFFF" for example. I tried to debug and found out, that hexstring, (In my opinion Serial.read()) works fine with FFFFFF .... but number is empty

Comment: It isn't working fine, `const char *hexString = Serial.read();` takes one *byte* and assigns it as **string pointer**, as a matter of fact it doesn't even compile: `sketch.ino:22:41: error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*' [-fpermissive]`. Number is `0` because `hexstring` is invalid.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. Sorry, I am new

Comment: I'll try be more clear then :). How does this [code](https://hastebin.com/zilaramune.cpp) even compile on your machine?

Comment: const char *hexstring is not the hex I wrote...number does not exist

Comment: Now it's my turn to not understand you :)

Comment: Whops, sorry :P 
There are no errors.
I write "FFFFFF" and *hexstring  = �"�b�b�b�b�b

Comment: Am I right that you are printing the content of `hexstring` back through *Serial* and `�"�b�b�b�b�b` is what you receive on the *pc*?

Comment: try `char data[7]; data[6] = '\0'; if (Serial.available() >= 6) { for (byte i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { data[i] = Serial.read(); }; int number = strtol(&data, NULL, 16); int bg_color = map(number, 0, 0xFFFFFF, 0, 0xFFF); lcd.clear(bg_color); }`, be sure that you are not sending extra `\r\n` through the *serial monitor* when you press `[enter]` on the keyboard, or it will work only at the first iteration because I am not doing any *sanity check* on the input.

Comment: I just copied & pasted it because I don't really understand this. 

cannot convert 'char (*)[7]' to 'const char*' for argument '1' to 'long int strtol(const char*, char**, int)'

Comment: sorry I forgot to cast: `char data[7]; data[6] = '\0'; if (Serial.available() >= 6) { for (byte i = 0; i < 6; ++i) { data[i] = Serial.read(); }; int number = strtol((const char*) &data, NULL, 16); int bg_color = map(number, 0, 0xFFFFFF, 0, 0xFFF); lcd.clear(bg_color); }` The code loads *6 bytes* into a fixed-size and null-terminated array of *chars*, it converts the *string* to *int*, maps the value into the target *color space* and then sets the background color.

Comment: Hm. For me it's not working. I think it is better when I create my own method, with normal math :D

Comment: If you see `�"�b�b�b�b�b`  on *stdout* it's the `hexstring` that is *garbage*, not `strtol()` that isn't working. Good luck! ;)

Comment: For *future reference*, in the above code `number` should be declared to be `long` rather than `int`.